# How to evaluate directly the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices

How does evaluate the determinant of the following $(2n+1)\times (2n+1)$ matrix?
  \begin{equation}
    \det A = \begin{array}{|cccccccccc|cc}
      1       & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & & {\color{blue}{\text{row }1}}\\
      -1       & 2 & -1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0& & {\color{blue}{\text{row }2}} \\
      0       & -1 & 2 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0& & {\color{blue}{\text{row }3}} \\
      \vdots  & \vdots&  \vdots   & \ddots      & \vdots    & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots  & &{\color{blue}{\vdots}}\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0  && {\color{blue}{\text{row }j-1}}\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -1 & 3 & -1 & \dots & 0 & 0 &{\color{blue}{\rightarrow}}&  {\color{blue}{\text{row }j}}\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 & 2 & \dots & 0 & 0 && {\color{blue}{\text{row }j+1}} \\
      \vdots  & \vdots&  \vdots   & \ddots      & \vdots    & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots    & &{\color{blue}{\vdots}}    \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 2 & -1 && {\color{blue}{\text{row }2n}} \\ 
       0       & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -1 & 1 && {\color{blue}{\text{row }2n+1}}\\
    \end{array}
  \end{equation}
The coefficient $3$ is at the $j$-th row for some $2\leq j\leq 2n$.
Therefore, 
$$
\det (L_{A_{11}}) = (-1)^n 2^{n-1}.
$$ 
If $n+1\leq i\leq 3n+1$ we denote the resulting matrix by $A_{12}$ after
deleting the $i$-th row and column of $L_A$. Then, by a
similar computation, we have 
$$
\det (L_{A_{12}}) = (-1)^n 2^{n}.
$$

> Should we thus conclude that 
>   $$
> \det A = (-1)^n 2^{n-1}n + (-1)^n 2^{n}(2n+1)=(-1)^n 2^{n-1}(5n+2)
> $$
>   is equal  to $(-1)^n 2^{n-1}(5n+2)$ ?